# Targeting .NET 4.0 gives invalid Win XP application since TFS .NET 4.5 upgrade

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-xp, .net-4.5, tfsbuild

We have a TFS build server (I think it's called a build controller in TFS terminology). It builds and deploys several solutions. One of these solutions, a Windows Forms project targeting .NET 4 full profile and x86, used to work fine on Windows XP, and now fails to run with the message:

> *.exe is not a valid win32 application on Windows XP

We have a build from 3 months ago that works fine and nothing relevant has changed in the source code since. But when requesting a new build from the build server now, the resulting .exe (with a lot of .dlls to support it) cannot be run on Windows XP 32-bit. The same build runs fine on Windows 7 32-bit and Windows 7 64-bit.

My best guess it that something installed on the build server in the last three months is making the difference. A lot of stuff has been installed, including .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2012 etc. Still, it shouldn't change a solution targeting 4.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is a question about build servers, C# and .NET _off-topic_ on Stack Overflow? The people who voted to close apparently only read question titles, not content...

Comment: Well, in spite of what you may think, Hans Passant, the problem is totally reproducible. If we install .NET 4.5 on the build server (or on our development machines), the resulting .exe fails on Windows XP. Even though the solution targets .NET 4, not 4.5. And if we remove .NET 4.5, the resulting .exe works on Windows XP. Pure and simple.

Comment: I am from Microsoft .NET Framework team. It is supported to build .NET4 apps using .NET4.5 toolset. I just met large company that's doing it. Can you send me repro project that reproduces the issue? Send to netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com.

Thanks, Varun Gupta .NET Framework Team

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.net 4.5 upgrades .net 4.0 so if you have .net 4.5 installed on your build server, and you're targetting .net 4.0, this isn't the same .net 4.0 that you have installed on XP. You cannot install .net 4.5 on XP. [This Blog](http://news.kynosarges.org/2012/08/01/no-net-4-5-for-xp2003/) goes in to more detail.

Basically if you want to support XP, you cannot use .net 4.5 / Visual Studio 2012. (or have them installed on your build machines)

Answer (score 1):

There was an [old hot big topic on MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c05a8c02-de67-47a9-b4ed-fd8b622a7e4a) that .NET 4.0 on machine with installed .NET 4.5 is different from .NET 4.0 with installed .NET 4.5 In other words one cannot reliably develop and test .NET 4.0 applications on/from machine with installed .NET 4.5 and has to mount separate development and testing machines/ environments

Though, there are a lot of answers in SO insisting on the opposite. Probably from the same authors who downvote any my answer contradicting it, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145323/async-targeting-pack-versions/16146361#16146361), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062590/async-ctp-not-working-in-vs-2010-sp1/16228189#16228189), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074401/asynchronous-programming-with-async-and-await/16097562#16097562)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late to matter for OP, but I ran into this issue and found a fix that happened to work for me. Building my project generates an .exe.config file in the output folder. This config has a startup section with:

```
supportedRuntime version="v.4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"
```

I changed the 4.5 to 4.0 and now my projects run on XP (Service Pack 2) without issue. All of the packages and dlls I link against are built for 4.0. I didn't look into it to figure out which one was the culprit here, but I suspect it's Microsoft.Practices.Unity since the config file appears to be related to the dependency injection I'm doing. Building on Win7 with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Platform ToolSet to use Visual Studio 2010. Then Rebuild, hopefully that might work for you

Comment: That page seems to target C++. I can't find the Platform Toolset settings in our C# project.

Answer (score 0):

The compilers included in .NET 4.5 take advantage of a hidden knowledge, .NET 4.5 is not supported for XP.  This allows them to do something that's been long overdue for .NET programs, they can finally change the target operating system version.  Which is encoded in the EXE and DLL header, it has always been set to Windows version 4.00 since .NET was first released.

You can see that target version number with SDK tools, the Dumpbin.exe /headers command displays it.  The Editbin.exe utility can change it after you build, using the /SUBSYSTEM option.  Which would be one way to patch your programs to make them run on XP.

Windows pays attention to this field in the EXE.  When it sees a target version of *less* than 6.00 then it will assume that the program was originally written to run on older versions of Windows, before Vista.  Which then turns on a few appcompat features.  The most drastic one is that it will assume that your program doesn't know anything about the fat borders on windows displayed when the Aero feature is enabled.  It will *lie* about the window size, returning a value that's 6 pixels less than the actual window size.  That lie can mystify some programmers a great deal when they try to do things like getting windows to line up.

With the target version set to 6.00, Windows will turn off lies like that.  And stops the program from running on XP, it doesn't know what version 6.00 means.  It only goes up to 5.02, assuming SP2 is installed.

No need to wind back to an old version of Visual Studio, the answer you accepted is wrong about that.  The workaround is a very simple one (you don't actually want to use Editbin.exe), simply target .NET 4.0 instead of 4.5.  .NET 4.0 is in fact available on XP.  The compilers accordingly keep the target OS version at 4.00.  If you are 300% sure about actually already targeting .NET 4.0 then there's something messed up in the build machine configuration.  Something nasty like using assembly references from c:\windows\microsoft.net or the GAC instead of c:\program files\reference assemblies.

Comment: The OP says he's already targeting .NET 4.0, and always has been. Only .NET was upgraded from 4.0 to 4.5.

Comment: Well, maybe, but it is just not the way it works.  Something is messed up about that build server, or his assumptions, it isn't clear from the question what that might be.   I've included the diagnostic to see what the compilers are actually generating so he'll have a secondary way to check what the build server is doing.

Comment: The problem got solved by uninstalling .NET 4.5 from the build server. Even if the solution does not target 4.5 but only 4.0. In other words, installing .NET 4.5 ruins .NET 4.0. Nice work, Microsoft.

Comment: Well, that ends any opportunity to find out what was wrong about that server's setup.  It will be back some day.  Not sure why you think this is something that Microsoft did wrong, you'll need to look within a 50 feet radius, give or take.

Comment: @HansPassant, `"the answer you accepted is wrong about that...simply target .NET 4.0 instead of 4.5"`. With all my respect to you, I cannot be calm about such answers and insisting on them. I fail to install or run  such ".NET 4.0 targeted" app in my Windows XP SP3 (with .NET 4.0) and receive answers from support that the problems are on my side because their developers targeted .NET 4.0 from VS2012 !

Comment: Well, keep your socks on, no need to get worked-up about it.  I carefully studied the effect of the target .NET version on the EXE header and documented how you can too.  Maybe your VS2012 and .NET version isn't the same, the updates have been coming fast and furious.  What I found out is valid of VS2012 Update 1, an update that brought back XP compatibility in C++ projects.  It might have affected .NET projects too.  Just try it.

Comment: Well, in spite of what you may think, Hans Passant, the problem is totally reproducible. If we install .NET 4.5 on the build server (or on our development machines), the resulting .exe fails on Windows XP. Even though the solution targets .NET 4, not 4.5. And if we remove .NET 4.5, the resulting .exe works on Windows XP. Pure and simple.